# How to take photo/record video on RPi as a webcam server?

Tags: camera, streaming-video

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-Raspberry-Pi-Webcam-Server-and-Stream-/#discuss) on making RI a webcam server and live stream video to laptop. I did it.

The reason I want to live stream video is get a preview of the photo I am about to take, or see the video while I am recording it.

I am using a USB camera. I know to record a video you use the command:

> ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -r 25 -s 640x480 -i /dev/video0 nameofmyvideo.mp4

But it said "Error selecting input 0 VIDIOC_S_INPUT: Device or resource busy". I am guess because it's live streaming. I have not idea what the message means.

Now, how to record a video while the camera is live streaming?

Comment: Give this a try. It's a possible solution for web streaming and taking pictures (almost simultaneously). https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gqv1_-f2H98

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're correct, you can't access the device with 2 separate programs at once. That said, you can certainly record and view with some careful programming (my choice would be Flask web server in Python).

A quicker approach would be to use the motion and motioneye packages with the output_all enabled. You can even download a distribution ready to go to test it: 
https://github.com/ccrisan/motioneyeos

> output_all
>
> Type: Boolean Range / Valid values: on, off Default: off Option Topic
>   Picture are saved continuously as if motion was detected all the time.
>
> This feature is not meant to be the normal mode of operation.
>   Especially not if you have the output_normal or output_motion features
>   enabled since it will keep on saving pictures on the disk and you will
>   soon run out of disk space. So be careful with this command.
>
> If your frame rate is 10 pictures per second motion will save 10 new
>   picture pr second until the disk is full.
>
> It does all the normal actions that are done when motion is detected.
>   It saves pictures on the harddisk, execute external scripts, etc as
>   fast as the frame rate of the camera. So it is probably a good idea to
>   run with a low framerate when using this feature and to not use
>   activate all the features that saves files on the disk.
>
> The idea of this feature is that you can turn the feature on and off
>   for a short period of time to test or to generate continuous mpeg
>   films when needed.